# Can I reduce rendering time by adapting computer hardware?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hardware

Can I reduce rendering time by adapting system requirements? And if I can, what are the things I have to consider while adapting my Computer? If I want to get output instantly withing few minutes even when I set the sampling value to 2000 +, how I have to modify my system?

Comment: There are quite a few things you can do: Get more GPUs with as many cuda cores as you can, so you can render more tiles simultaneously. Get multiple CPU processors with multiple cores and lots of RAM. Split the rendering load between different computers to create a render farm...